# Angular-Material slow tab transition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I used Angular Material's tab to create a tab with many forms.
[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-aanv2p?)

Since it takes a long time to navigate to these heavy tabs, I wanted to show a dialog that the tabs are loading.
However, with the "click" or "selectedTabChange" event of mat-tab-group, the screen freezes before the dialog appears, and the dialog appears only after the tab is moved.

```
<md-tab-group (click)="openDialog()">
  <md-tab label="light-page1">
    <app-light-page></app-light-page>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="heavy-page">
    <app-heavy-page></app-heavy-page>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="light-page2">
    <app-light-page></app-light-page>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

Is it possible to make the screen freeze with Loading displayed when moving to a heavy tab?

Comment: are you using Angular 2.0???? from Angular 7 allow `cdk-virtual-scroll-view` and I think that this should be your aproach -really to have at time 10000 "inputs" is really heavy you has in tabs or not

Comment: I used `cdk-virtual-scroll-view` and it worked! Thanks for the radical solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redesigned the page using `cdk-virtual-scroll-view` [link](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview) to reduce the loading time.